# How to write a custom syntax mode in Coda 2 for Qooxdoo

Tags: syntax-highlighting, qooxdoo, coda

I would like to make a custom syntax .mode file for [Qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org) in [Coda 2](http://panic.com/coda) to get the code navigator work properly.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Code 2 but I use a TextMate qooxdoo plugin which does have a custom syntax as well. Maybe that might give you a litte help:
http://sourceforge.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/TextMate/trunk/qooxdoo.tmbundle/Syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage